# Adding arbitary links in a RichTextBox control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

Is it possible to add links that will just be links, i.e. not urls or file links but thinks like:

[click me](http://www.yahoo.com), [do something](http://www.yahoo.com)

etc

Is this possible? IF so, how do I do this? Basically I just need to mark certain text inside the RichTextBox as links so I can perform operations depending on what link is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this code project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RichTextBoxLinks.aspx